# How does Kestrel select among similar or duplicated TLS certificates?

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server

Supposing you have imported two wildcard certificates for "*.foobar.net" in the Windows certificate store (certlm.msc) having different expiration dates and the `appsettings.json` configured as bellow. Which certificate Kestrel will choose to serve requests?

```
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "HTTPS": {
        "Url": "https://*",
        "Certificate": {
          "Store": "My",
          "Subject": "*.foobar.net",
          "Location": "LocalMachine"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

By experiment, it seems to select the one with the greater expiration date, but I haven't found any documentation describing the actual criteria.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `Path` to the cert .pfx
If you have it in a separate store you can set that too
The example are [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but the question is related to the Windows certificate store. I'll mention that to be more specific.